# Automatically run specific tests on file change?

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, tdd, laravel-5.3

I'm looking for a way to automatically run specific tests when specific files are changed, similar to what you can do with a *Guardfile* in *Ruby on Rails*. I was wondering if there is a way to do this with *Laravel Elixir* or with gulp (I.e. *gulpfile.js*)

Here is an example of what I'm looking for:

```
watch('^app/Http/Controllers/(.+)(Controller)\.php$', function($match) { 
    return ["tests/{$match[1]}"];
});

watch('^app/Policies/(.+)(Policy)\.php$', function($match) { 
    return ['tests/' . str_plural($match[1])];
});

watch('^app/User.php$', function($match) { 
    return [
        'tests/Admin',
        'tests/Auth',
        'tests/Users',
    ];
});
```

Comment: a cron job could be used but the minimum frequency is per minute

Comment: How would I do this in development environment using homestead? Any links to examples would be greatly appreciated

Comment: as far as i can tell the same way you set up cron jobs anywhere else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `grunt` and a couple of the plugins, if that is an option for you. I do this for PHP, javascript and CSS source files and it works a treat.

Example gruntfile, trimmed down:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        watch: {
            grunt: { files: ['Gruntfile.js'] },
            php: {
                files: ['src/**/*.php'],
                tasks: ['phpunit']
            }
        },
        shell: {
            phpunit: 'phpunit --testsuite Unit' // or whatever
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-shell');

    grunt.registerTask('phpunit', ['shell:phpunit']);
};
```

You'll need [grunt-contrib-watch](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch) and [grunt-shell](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-shell)

This will now run `phpunit` any time a php file within `src/` changes, *provided* you have the `grunt watch` task running in the background. You can of course restrict and change which files you listen for with regex patterns within files section of the watch task.

**EDIT:**

To run specific tests based on a specific file change rather than a wildcard-update-all, you would have the following:

```
watch: {
    grunt: { files: ['Gruntfile.js'] },
        UserSrc: {
            files: ['app/**/UserController.php'], // The ** matches any no. of subdirs
            tasks: ['UserControllerTests']
        }
    },
    shell: {
        userTests: 'phpunit tests/User' // To run all tests within a directory, or:
        //userTests: 'phpunit --testsuite UserController // to run by testsuite
    }
}
// ... Other config

grunt.registerTask('UserControllerTests', ['shell:userTests']);
// ... more tasks
```

Using test suites is the better route to use if your User tests span multiple directories. So if you want to run all test files within tests/Users and tests/Auth etc, you'd have a testsuite in your phpunit.xml file that would run those. Something like:

```
// ...
<testsuite name="UserController">
    <directory suffix="Test.php">tests/Users</directory>
    <directory suffix="Test.php">tests/Auth</directory>
    // .. Other directories
</testsuite>
// ...
```

Comment: I was looking at the 2 links but I'm just not sure how I would apply this given the example in my question. If you can update your answer using my example, I will accept this answer.

Comment: no problem. can you clarify what you need though, is it to match certain files? So if one file changes, that causes tests to run for other related/specific files?

Comment: Yes, to match certain files and cause certain tests to run. Please take a look at the examples in my question. For example when `UsersController` is updated, run all tests in the `tests/Users` directory. I'd appreciate if you could match the same regular expressions that I have posted on my question. Thank you for your help

Comment: I asked another related question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41730127/6615480)