# How to automatically run a single phpunit test when it is updated?

Tags: php, laravel-5, gruntjs, phpunit

I am using Laravel 5.3 and unfortunately when you run `gulp tdd`, a change to 1 file runs the entire test suite which now takes nearly 2 minutes. With reference to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41274203/automatically-run-specific-tests-on-file-change), I started using *Grunt* to run specific tests when specific files are changed. Sample Gruntfile below:

**Gruntfile.js:**

```
var phpunit = 'vendor/bin/phpunit ';
grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    watch: {
        HomeSrc: {
            files: [
                'app/Http/**/HomeController.php',
                'resources/views/home/**/*.php'
            ],
            tasks: ['HomeTests']
        },
    shell: {
        HomeTests: { command: phpunit + 'tests/Home' },
    }
});
```

However, now my Gruntfile is getting pretty long and I would like to run specific test files when they are changed.

**Questions**

1. Is there a more efficient way to do this? (better organization of the Grunfile or using Gulp instead)
2. How can I run a specific test when its file is changed?

Example:
When `tests/Home/IndexTest.php` is changed, automatically run `vendor/bin/phpunit tests/Home/IndexTest.php`

Comment: The lines of code in the grunt file are long. It's not a big deal but I was wondering if there's a way that I can shorten them using regular expressions to locate the appropriate test file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, to handle this you will need to catch the matched file name and dynamically set a variable to use as the unit test file. This should cover all basic mappings where the test class name is exactly the same name as the file name it is within, and supports namespaces so not all test files with the same class name will be picked up by the filter.

Example:

```
grunt.initConfig({
    // .. snipped ..
    unitTestFile: 'to_be_replaced',
    watch: {
        php: {
            files: ["tests/**/*.php"],
            tasks: ["shell:unitTest"],
            options: {
                spawn: false
            }
        }
    },
    shell: {
        unitTest: {
            command: "phpunit --filter <%= unitTestFile %>"
        }
    }

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-shell');

    grunt.event.on('watch', function (action, filepath) {
        if (grunt.file.isMatch(grunt.config('watch.php.files'), filepath)) {
            var testFile = filepath.replace(/\\/g, '\\\\');
            grunt.config('unitTestFile', testFile.replace(/.php/, ''));
        }
    });
};
```

So, a file named `tests\unit\ApplicationTest.php` and within a namespace of `tests\unit` if changed will now run that as a test. The resulting command being:

```
phpunit --filter tests\\unit\\ApplicationTest // only runs in this namespace
```

Comment: What would happen if you have two tests with the same name, Ex: `tests/Home/IndexTest.php` and `tests/Users/IndexTest.php`? Would they both be run based on `{ command: "phpunit --filter <%= unitTestFile %>" }`

Comment: If you use namespaces in your test suite (which you would have to to have the same name tests) then no. See updated answer - this now accommodates namespaces and the argument passed to `--filter` is a namespaced class.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider the following solution:

1. Utilize an external `.json` which includes an array of files/paths you intend to watch and ultimately run as a unit test.
2. Dynamically generate the [Targets](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#task-configuration-and-targets) for both the `watch` and `shell` Tasks.

*(Both points above will certainly help to reduce the lines of code.)*

The following ***gist*** demonstrates this:

---

#### JSON

Lets assume we have a file named `test-mappings.json` with each file path *(as per point 1)* specified as followed and saved in the projects root directory alongside `Gruntfile.js`

```json
[{
    "file": "tests/testA.php"
},{
    "file": "tests/testB.php"
},{
    "file": "tests/testC.php"
},{
    "file": "tests/testD.php"
}]
```

#### Gruntfile.js

Use a `Gruntfile.js` configured as follows:

```js
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    'use strict';

    var mapping = grunt.file.readJSON('test-mappings.json'),
        watch = {},
        shell = {};

    // Dynamically create the targets for 'watch' and 'shell' tasks.
    mapping.forEach(function(config, index) {
        watch[index] = {
            files: [config.file],
            tasks: [index]
        };

        shell[index] = {
            command: 'vendor/bin/phpunit ' + config.file
        };

        // Register the shell target
        grunt.registerTask(index, ['shell:' + index ]);
    });

    grunt.initConfig({
        watch: watch,
        shell: shell
    });

    // Handy for dev - logs generated targets
    //grunt.log.writeln(JSON.stringify(grunt.config(), null, 2));

    require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

    grunt.registerTask('default', [
        'watch'
    ]);
};
```

Notice each Target for both the `watch` and `shell` Tasks are dynamically generated, and configured, according to the file list specified in `test-mappings.json`.

To see the configuration of the auto generated targets you can simply uncomment the line reading `grunt.log.writeln...`, before running `$ grunt`, and it will be printed to the console.

---

#### Running the task

1. Type `$ grunt` via the CLI.
2. Make an edit to one of the files listed in `test-mappings.json` and save it.
3. The `watch` task will then run the corresponding `shell` command.

#### Additional notes

1. Currently the files are listed in an external `.json`, however they could reside in the `Gruntfile.js` and be assigned to a variable if preferred.
2. Or, the files could be obtained using the appropriate [globbing](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#globbing-patterns) pattern(s) and modifying the gist above as necessary. In which case iterating over [grunt.file.expand](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.file#grunt.file.expand) will be handy for that, instead of the current `mapping` array.
3. The following grunt plugins were used for the above gist:

   - [grunt-contrib-watch](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch)
   - [grunt-shell](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-shell)
   - [load-grunt-tasks](https://github.com/sindresorhus/load-grunt-tasks)

---

#### Update:

The following `Gruntfile.js` is for the approach previously mentioned in point no. two under the *Additional notes* secton (i.e. Globbing instead of an external JSON filepath config).

```js
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    'use strict';

    var tests = 'tests/**/*.php',
        watch = {},
        shell = {};

    grunt.file.expand(tests).forEach(function(filepath, index) {
        watch[index] = {
            files: [filepath],
            tasks: [index]
        };
        shell[index] = {
            command: 'vendor/bin/phpunit ' + filepath
        };
        grunt.registerTask(index, ['shell:' + index]);
    });

    grunt.initConfig({
        watch: watch,
        shell: shell
    });

    require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

    grunt.registerTask('default', [
        'watch'
    ]);

};
```

Answer (score -1):

**Using command line**

go to your project folder then run below suitable command

Run all test class files

`phpunit`

Run specific test class file

`phpunit ./tests/ExampleTest.php`

or

Run specific test case from class file run below command

`phpunit --filter testBasicExample ./tests/ExampleTest.php`

Comment: I want it to run automatically